# AndEngine GLES 2.0 - Power button issue - App Crashes onResume()

Tags: android, crash, andengine, android-logcat

App crashes when i press power button to lock screen and press it again to unlock screen.
App crashes after scren gets unlocked.

This is a stackTress i got in logcat:

```
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onResumeGame(BaseGameActivity.java:222)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$4.run(BaseGameActivity.java:373)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-09 18:46:57.254: E/AndroidRuntime(25354):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Nullpointer Exception at onResumeGame() method of BaseGameActivityClass.

I have added this line in "activity" tag of manifest

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

in my GameActivity which extends BaseGameActivity i have added this

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      mEngine.stop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
       super.onResume();
       mEngine.start();
    }
```

What is wrong?
What shall i do to stop crashing game on power button issue?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever onResume() method is called it again recreate all your resources.
So at the time of your onResume() method call the controller does not found mEngine instance. Because of this it fires an error NullPointerException.

The task of onPause() method is to stop the music and sound and onResume() method is to again play sound and music. These methods are not used for any other purpose in android game development particularly in AndEngine.

Comment: my resources are very huge. It takes some seconds to load them. and i'm using spritesheets. bt the same thing works for Gingerbread and don't work only for ICS and above. Why is this so?

Comment: No you have to change you development strategy otherwise it creates a big problem later. because in market so many devices are available.

Comment: I'm loading all of my resources at the time of SplashScene itself. and later just manipulating them accordingly in GameScene.

Comment: If your game contain more graphics then you have to divide it into multiple segment. At a time only required graphics are loaded into the memory.